# Writing for Always On Display

Tags: java, android, galaxy

I have the new Galaxy S7 and I wanted to try messing around with my own Always-On Display mode content, but I'm having trouble finding any sources.

Is there currently any library or hack available to hook into this feature?

Comment: Don't say "Is there a library for X", say "How do I do X?".  (Though if you can't find anything on your own, you might have better luck asking Samsung instead of us.)